# Flash Organisation Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, charts

I've been searching for a library that can render organisation charts in either flash and/or javascript(preferably jQuery). I know of several javascript and/or flash chart libraries but none of them seem to be able to render an organisation chart such as this: http://www.fsai.ie/images/org_chart.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iLog Elixir](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/ilogelixir/) seems to have what you're looking for, in Flash/Flex. It's a commercial product and quite expensive, though. I Also found [these blog posts](http://blogs.ilog.com/elixir/category/ilog-elixir/org-chart/) (apparently by people from their dev team) where you can see a bit of how org charts are implemented in their product.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried [Google Org Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html). It is free and pretty simple to use. I have used it to create a dynamic org chart in SharePoint. There are a few [issues](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=org%20chart&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) with it. But overall I was satisfied with it.

Answer (score -1):

have you considered just embedding something like gliffy?  it has it's own versioning and editing.  Do you need to just render something already created or enable visio creation?